# Connect node.js and signalr via sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, signalr

Is there anyway to send data though sockets from Node.JS to SignalR? I have a Node.JS app that sends realtime information as JSON format. The other app it's an MVC C# app that uses SignalR to send the data to the client via socket. I want tosen data from de nodejs to signalr and signal send that info to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider better solution for internal communication between processes. SignalR is meant to be used between .Net server and client using different authentication, handshake, protocol and network layer methods, which is inefficient for internal server communication.

Take a look on ZeroMQ, is well simple and very easy to use tool, meant especially for such cases. It has bindings for most languages including .Net and node.js.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Incorporated 0MQ to the project and now we are pushing data from the Node.JS + 0MQ and C# + 0MQ it's pulling the data. Now we are able to send the data processed by C# to the client view with SignalR. =D

Comment: Well done, I assume it was straight forward and simpler than you thought initially it will be?

Comment: Yes, it was easier and faster than we thought initially. 0MQ it's a good tool and I'm starting to think on more projects using this tool.

Comment: the signalr protocol is pretty light weight.  probably lighter than the hassle of yet another layer with configuration, support and all the related fun.

Comment: But it will use WebSockets to communicate, right? If yes, then there are few things to consider, first of all - WebSockets data framing, and masking. Second is big messages - will be split in chunks. Third, is TCP.
ZeroMQ will use most efficient protocol (own implementation of TCP-like protocol, that is far lighter for internal communication), and no any data-framing as well as no data protocols at all.
For internal communication, is better to use tools that are made for that, not the tools that are made for web service (even if it works). You could even use just files :) but dont..

Answer (score 0):

There is js client for browser to communicate with Signal R server. 
http://www.nuget.org/packages/SignalR.Js
You probably can extract js file from it and run from Node.js.

And probably standard Socket.IO will just work, you need to subscribe to proper events and go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a node.js client for signalR that doesn't require jQuery I started this one.  It intentionally only supports websockets.

https://npmjs.org/package/signalr-client

Comment: I'm guessing you'd get a lot more usage by having a public source code repo and issue tracker on GitHub, BitBucket, etc.  I'm quite hesitant to use projects that don't have that.